# How to translate ROI in gray (monochrome) on OpenCV for android?

Tags: android, opencv

How to convert ROI in gray (monochrome) on OpenCV for android?

I try that, but it does not work:

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
   Mat image = inputFrame.rgba();
   Rect roi = new Rect(300, 50, 50, 10);
   Mat sub =image.submat(roi); 
   Imgproc.cvtColor(sub, sub, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);
   sub.copyTo(image.submat(roi));
   return image;
}
```

and

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
   Mat image = inputFrame.rgba();
   Rect roi = new Rect(300, 50, 50, 10);
   Mat sub =image.submat(roi);
   Imgproc.cvtColor(sub, sub, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);
   sub.copyTo(image.submat(roi));
   return image;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

The the problem in above code is that you are trying to copy single channel Mat (GRAY) to multi channel Mat (RGBA).

So you need to convert GRAY to RGBA before copying back to original RGBA image.

Change your code to

```
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
   Mat image = inputFrame.rgba();
   Rect roi = new Rect(300, 50, 50, 10);
   Mat sub =image.submat(roi); 
   Imgproc.cvtColor(sub, sub, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY);
   Imgproc.cvtColor(sub, sub, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGBA);
   sub.copyTo(image.submat(roi));
   return image;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Haris was right at identifing the problem but the solution he provided is unnecessary. In your original code, you **do not need** to copy `sub` back to `image`, this line:

```
//sub.copyTo(image.submat(roi));
```

Because changing `sub` like this:

```
Imgproc.cvtColor(sub, sub, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY, 4);
```

Will also alter `image`. This happens because calling `submat` does not create a new image, it just creates a reference region withing your original `image`.

So, to have a grey region in your color image all you should need is this:

```
Mat image = inputFrame.rgba();
Rect roi = new Rect(300, 50, 50, 10);
Mat sub = image.submat(roi);
Imgproc.cvtColor(sub, sub, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY, 4);
```

**Notice the last parameter of `cvtColor`, that is the resulting number of channels.** Rgba has 4 channels.